# Setup 'trust-certificate-pem' property in YAML config format

Tags: yaml, quarkus, application.properties

Im trying to setup a trust certificate in my Quarkus application for my postgres connection.
Sadly I wasted my time yesterday, by not noticing that I configured the property wrong.
That lead to a `io.vertx.core.VertxException: SSL handshake failed` error.

The main cause was that I converted the [example config](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#quarkus-reactive-datasource_quarkus.datasource.reactive.trust-certificate-pem) of `application.properties` wrong to the `application.yml` format, since I am using the [YAML extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-yaml). After testing the application properties variant it worked.

Now the question: How do I set is up correctly in YML format ?

```
# Working application.properties format
quarkus.datasource.reactive.trust-certificate-pem=true
quarkus.datasource.reactive.trust-certificate-pem.certs=somefile.pem
```

```yaml
# Wrong YAML formats, which I have tried so far

# V1
quarkus:
   datasource:
      reactive:
         trust-certificate-pem: true
         trust-certificate-pem:
            certs: somefile.pem

#V2
quarkus:
   datasource:
      reactive:
         trust-certificate-pem: true
         trust-certificate-pem.certs: somefile.pem


#V3
quarkus:
   datasource:
      reactive:
         trust-certificate-pem: true
         trust-certificate-pem.certs: somefile.pem

#V4
quarkus:
   datasource:
      reactive:
         trust-certificate-pem:
            value: true
            certs: somefile.pem
```

Anyone got an idea ? 
I really wished the Quarkus team had a toggle switch to see a YAML example :/

Comment: That is not  the [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format, and the officially recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least Sept. 2006.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML specification has a miscellaneous tag for `null`. This is the `~` (tilde) sign.

The following config will work

```yaml
quarkus:
  datasource:
    reactive:
      trust-certificate-pem:
        ~: true
        certs: somefile.pem
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't knew that